# Why is accessible a reserved word in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Why was accessible added as a reserved word to mysql and what is it used for? Is there documentation for it because I cannot find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what i gathered , it looks like `ACCESSIBLE`, `READ-ONLY` and `READ-WRITE` are access modes from [TABLESPACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-tablespace.html)s. But there is no documentation.

If you want to know how and when to use it , you will have to read [Oracle's documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17120/tspaces.htm).

After searching the mysql 5.1 (when they were introduced) source and trying out some keywords in google, i managed to come across [this commit](http://lists.mysql.com/internals/31529). From there a bot of digging in related variables/types in source, i found about request for adding TABLESPACE's in 5.0 > documentation in 5.1 > usage examples in Oracle docs.

Answer (score 0):

From the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-1.html#ftn.id448924):

> "The following are new reserved words
>   in MySQL 5.1: ACCESSIBLE LINEAR
>   MASTER_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT  RANGE
>   READ_ONLY READ_WRITE"

There doesn't appear to be any documentation outlining the use of `ACCESSIBLE`, so it's likely reserved for future use.